# Two Layouts for row in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-adapter

I have two layouts that are used according to product availability (available and missing) in stock. I tried to use them but without success, so I created a standard layout and change the Shape that contains the settings for each case. This is the best way to do? How can I use both in my Layouts APPLICATION?
Ps .: Remember that the ListView will not be with alternating colors (zebra style), but according to product availability.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using ServiceClass.Auvo_WebService;
using Android.Content;
using AppClass_Mobile;

public class AdapterProduct : BaseAdapter
{
    private Activity _Activity = null;

    private static   Product[] _ListOfProduct;

    public static    User _InstaceOfUser;

    public static    LayoutInflater _Inflater = null;

    private View   _View;

public AdapterProduct(Activity activity, Product[] listOfProduct)
{
    _Activity = activity;

    _ListOfProduct = listOfProduct;

    try
    {
        _Inflater = (LayoutInflater)_Activity.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    _View = convertView;

    ViewHolderProduct holderProduct;

    try
    {
        if (_View != null)
            holderProduct = _View.Tag as ViewHolderProduct;

        else
        {
            _View = _Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LayoutGenericProd, null);

            holderProduct = CriaHolder(position);
        }

        PopulaHolder(holderProduct, position);

        _View.Tag = holderProduct;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return _View;
}

private void PopulaHolder(ViewHolderProduct holderProduct, int position)
{

    if (_ListOfProduct[position].ThisProductIsOk)
    {
        holderProduct.descrProd.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Layout.ShapeRoundedCornerOut);

        holderProduct.descrProd.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
    }

    else
        holderProduct.descrProd.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Layout.ShapeRoundedCornerIn);

    holderProduct.descrProd.Text = _ListOfProduct[position].Name;

    holderProduct.lastUpDate.Text = _ListOfProduct[position].DataProduct.ToString("HH:mm");
}

private ViewHolderProduct CriaHolder(int position)
{
    ViewHolderProduct holderProduct = new ViewHolderProduct();

    holderProduct.descrProd = _View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.descrProd);

    holderProduct.lastUpDate = _View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lastUpDate);

    return holderProduct;
}

public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
{
    return null;
}

public override long GetItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public override int Count
{
    get { return _ListOfProduct.Length; }
}


public int GetCount()
{
    return _ListOfProduct.Length;
}

public void AddItem(Product product, User User)
{
    try
    {
        if (User.SerialNum == _InstaceOfUser.SerialNum)
            AddPordInList(product);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

private void AddPordInList(Product product)
{
    Array.Resize(ref _ListOfProduct, _ListOfProduct.Length + 1);

    _ListOfProduct[GetCount() - 1] = product;

    this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ViewHolderProduct : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView  descrProd { get; set; }
    public TextView  lastUpDate { get; set; }
    public ImageView statusProd { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Use getViewTypeCount and inflate views according to the type: (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount())

Comment: @IuriiO when i create GetItem method, i receive this error message:"Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceClass.User' to 'Java.Lang.Object'", but if make casting (Object) do not resolve. I troed this `public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return _ListOfProduct[position];
    }`